# How to configure Java RestClient to talk to ElasticCluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running ES v6.3.2. I have 2 master nodes and 2 data nodes in my cluster (lets call them M1 & M2 and D1 & D2). Lets say they are running on following IPs

```
M1 : 10.20.30.1:9200
M2 : 10.20.30.2:9200
D1 : 10.20.30.3:9200
D2 : 10.20.30.4:9200
```

I am communicating with the elastic search using the Low Level Java Rest Client.

On my local machine, I had only 1 instance running and I was communicating over (localhot:9200).

```
HttpHost httpHost1 = new HttpHost("localhot", 9200, "http");
```

My question is shall I build 4 HttpHost instances to talk to ES Cluster, or should I put all 4 ES instances behind the load balancer and build 1 HttpHost instance to talk to it?

Comment: First off, you should never communicate with the master nodes directly, let them manage the cluster and not handle search/index requests. Then, you can simply use two HttpHost instances for your D* nodes. Using a load balancer is also ok, although you're adding another hop in your communication path, which may induce some additional latency.

Comment: @Val I just tried, If I use 2 HttpHost instances for my 'D' node and at some point one of the node goes down, then my communication is failing. Is there any configuration I have to do to make sure in this case request should go to only the node which is in running state?

Comment: You could also use the Sniffer instead of providing all the nodes: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_usage.html

Comment: It might be a good idea to keep behind a load balance but take care about point the load balancer service check to ES url on that node. So, if the ES instance goes down the load balance doesn't redirect request to that node. But be careful about situations like brain split. That might get detected very late after a lot of debugging.